# Why does chrome always add a div on top of the body of html files?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am new to Web development and after inspecting a decent amount of websites, I have discovered that chrome always adds this `div` on top of the `body` :

```
<div id="screen-shader" style="
        transition: opacity 0.1s ease 0s; 
        z-index: 2147483647;
        margin: 0; 
        border-radius: 0; 
        padding: 0; 
        background: #111111; 
        pointer-events: none; 
        position: fixed; 
        top: -10%; 
        right: -10%; 
        width: 120%; 
        height: 120%; 
        opacity: 0.6000;
        mix-blend-mode: multiply; 
        display: none;
    "></div>
```

So I was just wondering what does it actually do ?

Comment: No it doesn't. I think you have a plugin installed. My guess would be something like: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-shader-smart-scree/fmlboobidmkelggdainpknloccojpppi?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a plugin installed. My guess would be something like: [Screen Shader | Smart Screen Tinting](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-shader-smart-scree/fmlboobidmkelggdainpknloccojpppi?hl=en)

**What does it do?**

It overlays a div over the entire viewport in order to adjust the colour/brightness/whatever.

This is what it looks like applied to just 50% of the viewport:

```html
<div id="screen-shader" style="
        transition: opacity 0.1s ease 0s; 
        z-index: 2147483647;
        margin: 0; 
        border-radius: 0; 
        padding: 0; 
        background: #111111; 
        pointer-events: none; 
        position: fixed; 
        top: -10%; 
        right: -10%; 
        width: 60%; 
        height: 120%; 
        opacity: 0.6000;
        mix-blend-mode: multiply; 
        display: fixed;
    "></div>
<img src="https://placeimg.com/360/180/animals" width="100%"/>
```

Comment: Thank you and I do have a screen shader in fact

Comment: @CHAMCHOUN Mystery solved! Feel free to accept my answer ;)

Comment: Also, the ["Night Shift"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/night-shift/fpnlpehjhijpamloppfjljenemeokfio) extension adds it.